# asdf current shows node, but zsh can't find node command

Tags: node.js, oh-my-zsh, asdf

I am new to asdf. I installed asdf on via brew and enabled the asdf plugin in oh-my-zsh. Then I installed nodejs by `asdf plugin add node` and `asdf install node`, my `.asdf current` returns this

```
$ asdf current
nodejs          21.6.1          /Users/gefei/.tool-versions
```

But when I then do `node`, I just got an error:

```
$ node
zsh: command not found: node
```

What's going wrong?

EDIT: `asdf reshim` does not help, but `asdf exec node` works.

PS: I am sorry for the title, but I just could not find a good title which meets the quality standards of SE. For any advice I would be grateful

Comment: Can you expand the post with how exactly you set up `asdf`? And does running `asdf exec node` work?

Comment: Also see this FAQ entry: [Shell not detecting newly installed shims?](https://asdf-vm.com/more/faq.html#shell-not-detecting-newly-installed-shims)

Comment: @JensV Yes, `asdf exec node` works, but `asdf reshim` does not help

Comment: And you verified that you added the correct line into your `.zshrc`? After you make changes to `.zshrc` you either need to resource the config or open a new shell to have the config applied.

Comment: @JensV I put some more explanation into the question. Basically I installed asdf by HomeBrew, and enabled the asdf plugin in oh-my-zsh. Currently I have the following plugins: `plugins=(git asdf virtualenv node)`. I did not change my `.zshrc` manually cause I think the `asdf` plugin of `oh-my-zsh` must suffice. Doesn't it?

Comment: I think that should be right... maybe try moving the asdf plugin after the node plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I spent about 40 minutes on this, and finally found a simple solution: I simply added the path `/Users/gefei/.asdf/shims/` to my `$PATH$` and then it works fine.

I actually don't know whose job it is to put a line to `.zshrc` to automate this, so I decided to write an answer to this question, hoping someone will find it helpful.